# Python, For loop counter do not update?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am writing a simple program which gives the list of all prime no. less than a given no. N. 
I am facing a problem that my for loop counter `check` in the function `primes_gen` else clause do not updates. Though, when i use the same logic without a function, as mention in the second code snippet, everything works correct.

Logic applied:-

1. when `n` passed to function is `<= 2`, blank list is returned
2. when `n` is `> 2`, `range(3,n,2)` identifies all the odd number. This is step 1 marked in first code snippet.
3. second for loop, marked with step 2, checks if no. is divisible to the all no.'s less than `i`. If yes then check counter is incremented by `+1` and this loop is ended with 'continue'
4. if check remains zero till the end of the for loop then `i` is appended to the list and the finally after completion of the loop list is returned.

Problem:-

-The list i got as a result was [2] which is wrong ans. so I wrote step 3, as marked in 1st snippet, and i found that my check counter do not updates after the 'continue', as shown in the output. when same logic is applied without a function as written in second code snippet everything works correct. 
I am not able to get what is going wrong here, why does `check` do not updates after `continue`?

```
contents =['10']

def prime_gen(n):
    num_list=[2]
    if n <=2:
        return []
    else:
        for i in range(3,n,2):    #step 1
            check=0
            for u in (2,i):       #step 2
                if i%u == 0:
                    check += 1
                    continue
            print (check,i)     #step 3
            if check == 0:
                num_list.append(i)
    return num_list

if __name__== '__main__':
    for j in range(len(contents)):
            print (int(contents[j]))
            num_list = prime_gen(int(contents[j]))
            print (str(num_list).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
```

Output

```
 10
 1 3
 1 5
 1 7
 1 9
 2
```

Expected ans is (when step 3 above is commented)

```
10
2, 3, 5, 7
```

Second code without function

```
contents = ['10']   #to-check


for i in range(len(contents)):
    target = int(contents[i])
    num_list= [2]
    for j in range(3,target,2):
        check = 0
        for u in range(2,j):
        if j%u == 0:
            check +=1
            continue
    if check == 0:
        num_list.append(j)
#print (num_list)
print (str(num_list).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
```

output

```
2, 3, 5, 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem took a second to find, but is very simple to solve.  The issue is at your "Step 2".  You have the line

```
for u in (2,i):       #step 2
```

That iterates `u` through all the variables in the tuple you provide, namely `2` and `i`.  Of course, `i%i` will be 0, so `check` will always be true.  What you want instead is this:

```
for u in range(2,i):       #step 2
```

This will iterate `u` through all the variables between `2` and `i`, as you intend.

See these two examples:

```
>>> i = 7
>>> for u in (2,i): print u,

2 7
>>> for u in range(2,i): print u,

2 3 4 5 6
```

Basically, you just forgot to use `range` in your for loop, and that's going to give you wildly different results than what you actually want.

Comment: so it was a pretty dumb mistake :'(.  Thanks Brien

Comment: No problem; we've all been there :)

Comment: @CbK, since this solved your problem, consider accepting this answer to show others that it was helpful for you.